# Adjust the amount of columns and rows for a HTML table by form submission in PHP

Tags: php, forms, html-table

I have created a form with 3 rows, each row have 5 columns, and each column contain 3 input box as below screen shot.

[image]

I would like to submit this form and generating a table. The structure of the table will determine by the form's data.

For example:

1. If I submit the form as below:

[image]

It will create a table like this:

[image]

(two rows, first row have two columns and second row have one column)

I suppose I need this write a huge of `if then else` code for this situation, do someone have an idea on writing this logic? Prefer to write it simple/tiny.

Welcome to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the algorithm, but implementing it in php should be simple enough

1. Loop over the entire post to see how many rows have been returned, and which row has the max columns.
2. Create a table
3. In first row, add the number of cells you require, such that the `colspan` for each cell is `maxCols / thisRowCols`
4. do this for all rows

The only caveat I see in this logic is if the result of `maxCols / thisRowCols` is not an integer, but you will have to either live with it, or think up a workaround :P

**EDIT**

If you are echoing the  from the php,

```
if(thisRowCols != maxCols) {
    echo("<td colspan=\"", maxCols / thisRowCols, "\">&nbsp;</td>");
} else {
    echo("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
}
```

If you are having the `<td>...` in the html code,

```
<td <?php if(thisRowCols != maxCols) { echo("colspan=\"", maxCols / thisRowCols, "\"");} ?> >&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how can I put the colspan in to the `<td>` which have different cell than other row?

Comment: Edited my answer, see if it answers your query